# Is one big burp enough after feeding my infant?

Tags: infant, feeding

I've read in many places that I should burp my baby for 5-10 minutes after feeding What I'm wondering is if it's ok to stop once the baby gives a nice loud burp, even if that was only a few seconds? Where does the 5-10 minute number come from? My interpretation would be "until a big loud burp or 5-10 minutes if you don't hear one". Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is to get the air out that the infant sucks into the stomach while feeding.

**Any burp is enough.** It can be one big one, a few small ones. If none is heard within something like 10 minutes, then you can assume that it just slowly evaporated over time.

With my son, he usually burped either immediately or within a minute or so, but sometimes also not until he got a fresh diaper (I'm guessing the change in orientation helped). Sometimes he didn't burp at all, but was fine anyway. But we tried to be aware to not put him in bed before having burped, or before waiting a while at least.

Comment: +1 We've used this approach for both of our kids and have never had any problems.

Answer (score 4):

I've found with my baby that it's more accurate to go by his behavior than by "rules". There have been times when he gave a *huge* burp and still seemed unhappy and gassy and had to get out a bit more air. There were times when he gave a teeny little burp, or just a few hiccups, and that was all he needed to calm down and be happy. Watch your baby - if he's still moving around and acting a bit agitated and unhappy and making those groaning gassy sounds, you should probably try a little longer. If he seems happy and content and nothing's bothering him, most likely it's safe to put him down.

(And note - my baby has often taken more than 10 minutes to burp, especially when he was very young and his digestive system wasn't completely developed... Once again, I don't think there's any magic number. Depends on the kid.)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the child.  My baby absolutely needed to be burped every 2 ounces of formula, no exceptions, until she was about 6 months old.  Our ped refused to speak to us once I had to stop breastfeeding, but the little advice we got out of one of his colleagues was that some babies do well with one big burp halfway through, but some babies need time every couple ounces to get that air out or they're miserable.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Every baby is different. However..I found out an easier way to burb baby is after feeding bottle or breast. I sit him up get as much burbs as I can. Then lie him down (on his back) till he starts to whinge or get agitated then bring him up for another burb.and in between times lying him down I talk and play and sing to him (that gives us bonding time as well) so I keep doing repeatedly till all burbs come out. Sometimes you might a but of spit out. But this is a trick I've learned from experience and my midwife also confirmed it

Comment: Hi, user16567, welcome to the site.  There's some good information in your answer, but I'm not sure it directly addresses the question.  The OP is asking if one big burp is sufficient, ie, if the baby burps once is that enough to burp.  You might want to edit your answer to more directly answer that. Thanks, and again welcome!